# Unabled to change UITableViewCell properties

Tags: uitableview, swift

I'm trying to change the accessory view / accessory type of my table view cells, but it doesn't work.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell?

    switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "enabledCell")
            cell!.textLabel?.text = "Alarm enabled"
            var enabledSwitch = UISwitch(frame: CGRectZero)
            cell!.accessoryView = enabledSwitch
        case 1:
            cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("calendarCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell
            cell!.textLabel?.text = "Calendar"
            cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
        default:
            cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell
            cell!.textLabel?.text = "Oops"
    }

    return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this isnt working for you. I created a new project. Made a ViewController with a tableView in it and copied/pasted your code. Works. I get 1 cell with a switch, another with a disclosure, and one with no accessor. Is your table working at all? If your app just crashes maybe your reuseIdentifiers are misspelled or something. Maybe you didnt link your tableView to your ViewController as the delegate/datasource. Good Luck!

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class MyTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return 3
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    var cell: UITableViewCell?

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "enabledCell")
        cell!.textLabel?.text = "Alarm enabled"
        var enabledSwitch = UISwitch(frame: CGRectZero)
        cell!.accessoryView = enabledSwitch
    case 1:
        cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("calendarCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell
        cell!.textLabel?.text = "Calendar"
        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    default:
        cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell
        cell!.textLabel?.text = "Oops"
    }

    return cell!
}
```

}